# how to figure out syntax error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query that keeps giving me a syntax error. The problem is, the error message is not helping me at all.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
   (SELECT     
        dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent.ultimateParentCompanyId, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.ciqCompany.companyId) AS Subsidiaries_Count, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.ciqCountryGeo.countryId) AS Countries_Count
    FROM         
        dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.ciqCompany ON dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent.companyId = dbo.ciqCompany.companyId  
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.ciqCountryGeo ON dbo.ciqCompany.countryId = dbo.ciqCountryGeo.countryId
    GROUP BY 
        dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent.ultimateParentCompanyId
     )
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ciqCompany ON ultimateParentCompanyId = dbo.ciqCompany.companyId
```

The stuff in brackets works fine when I execute it (i.e. it executes and returns a table). However, the last `INNER JOIN` is giving me the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

What's even worse, when I cut down the above statement to

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT     
        dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent.ultimateParentCompanyId, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.ciqCompany.companyId) AS Subsidiaries_Count, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.ciqCountryGeo.countryId) AS Countries_Count
     FROM         
        dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.ciqCompany ON dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent.companyId = dbo.ciqCompany.companyId 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.ciqCountryGeo ON dbo.ciqCompany.countryId = dbo.ciqCountryGeo.countryId
     GROUP BY 
        dbo.ciqCompanyUltimateParent.ultimateParentCompanyId
    )
```

I get a similar error -

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Why can't I select * from a query that is working fine?

Comment: The `Incorrect syntax near INNER` is due to a missing alias on the subquery. You'll have to give that first subquery in the `FROM` clause an alias of its own.

Comment: You have to name the subquery with an alias.

Comment: FYI, "SQL" is not the name of a database product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try aliasing your subquery. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 ....
) SUB
INNER JOIN dbo.ciqCompany 
ON SUB.ultimateParentCompanyId = dbo.ciqCompany.companyId
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Why do I need to do this though?

Comment: @Anne in this your subquery acts as a derived table and that has to have a name

Comment: Thanks! So SUB is the name for this table?

Comment: @Anne Exactly, it's an alias for derived table, hence join `ON SUB.ultimateParentCompanyId`

Answer (score -4):

Given the `dbo`, you're on MS SQL Server? You need to embed multiple joins in brackets:

```
SELECT ..
FROM table1
JOIN (table2 ON ...
    JOIN (table3 ON ...
        JOIN table4 ON ...
            etc...
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes I'm on MS SQL Server. However, why do I need to put brackets? The inner bit is working fine without brackets.

Comment: Access requires that, but SQL Server doesnt IIRC.